# How to monitor website requests from my home network?

Tags: wireless

I have set up a wireless wifi network through my pc, so that My younger brother can use Internet through his laptop. But I want to monitor which sites he is visiting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a solution I know which I implemented once which you can also use is configuration of syslog server.

I believe your brother and you are both using Ubuntu then you can configure your system as syslog server and his system as syslog client.

Which will send his log files to your system so that you can check what he is accessing.

See the link below on for more information on rsyslog(syslog) in Ubuntu:

[rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html)